# How to find the root mean square voltage of a Sine wave?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, matlab

I'm giving a code in matlab and have to answer some questions, I'm having some doubts on some of the questions I've done.

Original code:

**%Paremeter setting

A = 1; %Amplitude

f = 1; %frequency

P = 0; %Phase

time = 1.5; %time duration

N = 1000; %Sampling number

t = 0:time/(N-1):time;

%Generate sin wave

s = A*sin(2*pi*f*t+P);

%Draw figure

plot(t,s)

grid on

xlabel('Time')

ylabel('Amplitude')**

```
Questions:

1. Run the code and plot the figure; what is the period of the output signal?
2. Change the A = 0.5, then run the code; what is the root mean square voltage of the signal?
3. Change the f = 2, then run the code; what is the period of the output signal?
4. Change the P=pi/4, then run the code; what is the value of the single at time = 0?
```

**My answers:**

1. **one second**

2. **This is what's confusing me: The peak is o.707, do I divide this by 2 or $\sqrt2$?**

3. **0.5 seconds**

4. **0.707**

I'm having problems with question 2, but are the other answers correct?

Comment: Root mean square= $\sqrt {\dfrac {x_1^2+x_2^2+\ldots + x_{n-1}^2+x_n^2}n}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a sine wave (assumed symmetric around zero) the rms level is $\frac {\sqrt 2}2$ of the peak level.  This is because the average value of $\sin^2$ is $\frac 12$, which you can show by integration.

Comment: So I multiply 0.707 by ( (sqrt(2))/2 )?

Comment: That is correct.